# Export pure functional component without decorators

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, redux, jestjs

I'm trying to export a component without the decorators (connect() in this case)
for unit testing with `jest`.

So, how could I do this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export class Header extends Component {
    render(){
        return <pre>Header</pre>
    }
}

export default connect()(Header);
```

With this component (the export at the beginning doesn't work, it stills exports the connected component)

```
export let Header = props => {
    render(){
        return <pre>Header</pre>
    }
}

Header = connect()(Header);

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use different variable for your connected component as the following code:

```
export let Header = props => {
    render(){
        return <pre>Header</pre>
    }
}

let HeaderConnected = connect()(Header);

export default HeaderConnected;
```

Now you can import your `Header` freely without using `connect()`

Answer (score 2):

This can be done without even changing default export:

```
export let Header = props => {
    render(){
        return <pre>Header</pre>
    }
}

export default connect()(Header);
```

There may be no need to export original component for `connect` alone because most well-designed HOCs expose original component:

```
import Header from '...';
const OriginalHeader = Header.WrappedComponent;
```